# Find actual value of PHP variable

Tags: php, variables

I am having a real headache with reading in a tab delimited text file and inserting it into a MySQL Database.

The tab delimited text file was generated (I think) from a MS SQL Database, and I have written a simple script to read in the file and insert it into an existing table in my MySQL database.

However, there seems to be some problem with the data in the txt file. When my PHP script parses the file and I output the INSERT statements, the values in each of the fields are longer than they should be. For example, the first field should be a simple two character alphanumeric value. If I echo out the INSERT statements, using Firebug (in Firefox), between each of the characters is a question mark in a black diamond. If I var_dump the values, I get the following:

```
string(5) "A1"
```

Now, this clearly shows a two character string, but var_dump tells me it is five characters long!!

If I trim() the value, all I get is the first character (in this case "A").

How can I get at the other characters, even if it is only to remove them? Additionally, this appears to be forcing MySQL to insert the value as a BLOB, not as a varchar as it should.

Simon

UPDATE
If I do:

```
echo mb_detect_encoding($arr[0]);
```

I get a result of 'ASCII'. This isn't multibyte, is it??

Comment: Are you sure it's 'A1', and not 'A1<space><space><space>'? Remember that browsers will collapse multiple spaces down into a single one when they're rendering output in HTML mode. You may want to try print the value out with something like `print("<pre>*$var*</pre>");` and see if the *'s show up in the expected spot.

Comment: Well in Firebug I get *A*1* (Where the asterisks are actually these question marks on a black diamond). In answer to your point, I get a * at the beginning and a * at the end. Still none the wiser

Comment: Sorry, above should read 
#A#1# where # is black diamond with question mark

Comment: ASCII isn't multi byte (well it doesn't need to be stored multi byte). From memory it's only 127 characters, from US English only, and a lot are invisible control characters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, solved all these issues by opening the TXT file in notepad and saving it specifically as UTF-8.

I still don't know what encoding was used (maybe UNICODE??) but it's all sorted now

Comment: UTF8 is an encoding of Unicode. Perhaps it was an ISO standard.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like an encoding issue.

Are you running any strings through PHP functions which are not multi byte safe?

You may need to look at [multi byte aware functions](http://php.net/manual/en/ref.mbstring.php) in PHP.

Comment: Hmm, thought it might be an encoding issue. I am using sprintf(), but unsure whether this is mb safe or not. Not got much experience of multibyte strings. How can I write this to MySQL as a standard string?